# React-persist is not persisting state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I am trying to implement redux-persist in my reactjs application, i am trying to persist user info but whenever i do refresh all the information is cleaned up and i am redirected to the login page.

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./state/reducer";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "primary",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["user", "artist"],
  blacklist: ["alerts"],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const middleWare = [thunk];
const initialState = {};

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleWare))
);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

index.js for all reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import artistReducer from "./artistReducer";
import userReducer from "./userReducer";
import alertReducer from "./alertReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  artist: artistReducer,
  user: userReducer,
  alerts: alertReducer,
});
```

App.js

```
import { persistor, store } from "./store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
          <Router>
            <Fragment>
              <Navbar></Navbar>
              <Alerts></Alerts>
              <Switch> ...{ code continues }
```

Here i can see my data but on refresh it gets cleaned up
[image]

Comment: Have you tried not using `blacklist` and `whitelist` together in `persistConfig`? It's a bit of a contradiction to provide both, the examples on the github repo don't do this. Btw, a lot of projects in the redux ecosystem are a bit over-engineered. Persisting user info to local storage is not that complicated to begin with. You occasionally write the user state to localStorage as a JSON string (with setInterval or just on every state change). When the page loads, read from local storage and JSON.parse() what was saved there to put it into the preloadedState of the redux store creation.

Comment: well initially i tried using with either blacklist and whitelist but it didn't work. And absolutely you are right i could use local storage but i am trying to implement this for future use cases, this is just for the learning purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of exploring internet i found this issue locked on github [ https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/826#fromHistory ] and there was much voted comment on it by hackrit which states
"Hi guys,
I found a solution to this problem. (might not apply to all the cases, but worked for me).
The problem was caused by my default return in my reducer, which I returned {...state}.
Once I changed the default return to just return state, everything work as expected." and this suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In My case this same issue happen after updating expo version.

Solution:

```
// import FSStorage from "redux-persist-expo-fs-storage";
import FSStorage from "redux-persist-fs-storage";
/*
Import change
*/
const primary = {
key: "root",
timeout: 0,
version: 1,
keyPrefix: "",
storage: FSStorage(),
stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2, // see "Merge Process" section for details.
};
```

ADD keyPrefix: "", in config.
Hope this solutions work for others.